# French accents in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, encoding

I am using geoserver 2.11.2 and tomcat 8.5. I have some french accents in shapefile. The french accents looks fine when viewing the attributes in QGIS. But it appears as special characters when viewing in geoserver. Is there any configuration i need to do ?

Comment: does the font you are using support accents? did you set the character encoding of the shapefile datastore correctly?

Comment: Yes encoding is in utf-8.

Comment: can you attach a sample shapefile and sld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this with your data on my machine (ubuntu, geoserver 2.10.1).

[image]

As you can see I have accents in both the labels and the getFeatureInfo. I simply added the shapefile as a datastore with the encoding as UTF-8.

[image]